# mongoose query where id not in other model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

so I have this kind of model

```
const vetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true},
    email: {type: String, unique: true, trim: true,},
    expYear: {type: Number},
    KTP: {type: String, unique: true, trim: true},
    cert_id: {type: String, unique: true, trim: true, select: false},
})

const clinicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    vet: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectID, ref: 'vet'}],
)}
```

what I want to do is finding vet by username, which the vet ID is not included in the clinic based on clinic ID, the query to find the vet is `{username: {$regex: (?i)${keyword}.*}}`

for example, we have this data

```
Clinic = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e57a45836d300b188f4444a"),
    "vet": [ObjectId("5e0742fc9d4b20100f89b626"),ObjectId("5e53698fd2b9ee43e7693e01")]
}]

Vet = [
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e0742fc9d4b20100f89b626"),
    "username": "VetClinic"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e55df62576bc9811877033e"),
    "username": "VetNotClinic"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e53698fd2b9ee43e7693e01"),
    "username": "VetClinic"
},
]
```

what i want is if I find `Vet` it only shows `VetNotClinic` because `VetClinic` is included in the clinic's ID, any good query / agregate?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$nin` to query where a field is "not in" an array like so

```js
Vet.find({
username: {$regex: (?i)${keyword}.*},
_id: {$nin: clinic.vet}
})
```

Comment: so you mean `clinic` is the model?

Comment: @ericanthony clinic.vet would be the array of vets in a specific clinic from the clinics collection/model